# Await a thread wont work when dispatch inside of the thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await, dispatch

I'm running a Task in a new thread and want to wait for it to finish.

```
var a = "logic before the task starts";
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyHugeFunction(_token), _token);
var b = "logic after the task is finished";
```

It worked perfectly until I started to dispatch inside of the thread with:

```
 await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
 {
    SomeLogic();
 }));
```

The task itself works, but the await for my running task isn't working anymore. As soon as I am dispatching in the thread, the var b will be assigned in the main thread.

I already have some workarounds but I just wondered if I'm doing something stupid or this is caused by other circumstances

I'm working with C# 8.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: BeginInvoke returns immediately after passing the Action to the dispatcher queue. It is unclear what you are trying to do here. Perhaps use Invoke instead of BeginInvoke.

Comment: From an exception-handling perspective, prefer `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: @Clemens thank you! Invoke instead of BeginInvoke fixed it for me.

Comment: @Joe Dispatcher.InvokeAsync causes the same problem.  Just Invoke did it for me.
But thanks :)

Comment: The comment by Joe was not meant to solve your problem, but just to tell that *in case* you want to make an asynchronous Dispatcher invokation, InvokeAsync  is better suited than BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running a Task in a new thread and want to wait for it to finish.

You want to use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew` for that. `StartNew` is a dangerous, low-level API that should almost never be used, and in the few cases where you *should* use it, you should ***always*** pass a `TaskScheduler`.

> await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>

Imma stop you right there. First, you're explicitly creating an `Action` delegate with `async`, which results in an `async void` method, which should be avoided. Next, using `Dispatcher` to do any kind of `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` really shouldn't be done at all.

Instead, use the `Progress<T>` type. This keeps your logic in your background thread, which can pass objects as updates to the UI thread, and the *UI thread* decides how to display those progress updates in the UI. Note the nice separation of concerns there, which tends to go out the window whenever people start using `Dispatcher`.

Both `StartNew` and `Dispatcher` are commonly seen in SO answers and blogs, but they're suboptimal solutions regardless.